# Email reverse with hyperlink text

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

How would I use the CSS reverse method to reverse an email address to prevent spam with an added hyperlink?
So my page would say something like this:
Please contact the webmaster.

I would like the email to be available when a user clicks or hovers over the webmaster text.

It works fine without a hyperlink but I'm not sure how the structure changes.

```
Please report errors to the webmaster - <span class="reverse">ku.oc.evil@cba</span>
```

-

```
.reverse {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Initial state: https://jsfiddle.net/kfey3wxu/

Comment: I do not understand. You want to reverse an email? Like turn it back-to-front?

Comment: I also don't understand... you already did it! (Though spam bots have figured out that one decades ago, so this trick will **not** help you :) The simple logic that's used is: Search for `@`. Found? Great. Is there a `.` after the `@` ? No? than reverse and steal! :) (More complicated with a pattern of domains match in the case of `@eod.nhoj` but you got the point.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood your question, I re-read it. I have added this to your CSS:

```
div:hover + .reverse {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Then, in your HTML, I have added a div to your webmaster.

```
Please report errors to the
<div>webmaster</div>- <span class="reverse">ku.oc.evil@cba</span>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfey3wxu/2/). I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Yeah that covers the hover, is the hyperlink possible?

Comment: the hyper link to what? @lewishh

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/himuge/1/edit?html,js,output)***

The trick you're using will not prevent bots.

I can show you a way that I did to prevents *most* (all, till now :D ) of the sniffy bots,
and that's using JS (jQuery):

```
Contact us at: <span data-yumm="com">some.name\website</span>
```

The backslash `\` (you can also use `"` but I would not suggest that.) cannot be used as a valid email-anything so we're OK to use it as an `@`  replacer.

Here, 97% of bots will go away, since in the wild there's tons of websites where they'll find that `@` pointer they're interested in and won't lose much time on your page :)

Now it's time for our dear users and jQuery:

```
$('[data-yumm]').text(function(i, v){
  return v.replace("\\", "@") +"."+ $(this).data("yumm");
});
```

Still there's around some bots that *have* timeouts waiting for your page to be loaded but... hey there's also human bots that are paid to do that job and sadly you don't know who they are to rise the bid ;)

To convert the same to a `mailto:` link use the following:

```
$('[data-yummy]').html(function(i, v){
  var email = v.replace("\\", "@") +"."+ $(this).data("yummy");
  return "<a href='mailto:'"+ email +">"+ email +"</a>";
});
```

Comment: viewing page source displays an email address, i assume this doesn't work anymore?